# jQuery - Remove a drop down item if it is selected by user

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 drop down lists with a list of teams in drop down list taken from a database. I've put the code for the drop down lists below, I apologise it is written in JADE's template engine for HTML but this is how I've written the code. I have put my current jQuery script below as well.

At the moment, it sort of works, if I go from team 1 through to team 4 and select a team, then it works, but if I change my mind for one of the drop downs...then the whole list messes up as it has already removed certain items...

If I enter a team in team1, it should disappear from the rest of the lists....but if I change team 1, the team should appear in the rest of the lists again, but it doesnt at the moment.

Any ideas how to fix this?

JADE drop downs:

```
div.row
    label.control-label(for="team1") Team 1:
    div.controls
        select#team1(style='width: 160px;')
            include teamsDropDown
div.row
    label.control-label(for="team2") Team 2:
    div.controls
        select#team2(style='width: 160px;')
            include teamsDropDown
div.row
    label.control-label(for="team3") Team 3:
        div.controls
            select#team3(style='width: 160px;')
                include teamsDropDown
div.row
        label.control-label(for="team4") Team 4:
            div.controls
                select#team4(style='width: 160px;')
                    include teamsDropDown
```

teamsDropDown JADE:

```
-if(teamsList.length > 0){
    option
    -each team in teamsList
    option.teamDropDown(id="#{team.key}",value="#{team.key}") #{team.name}
-}else{
    No teams till now..
-}
```

jQuery script:

```
script(type='text/javascript')
$('select').change(function() {
 $('select').not(this).children('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').remove();
});
```

JFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/m8QCZ/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this can feed your needs:

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m8QCZ/50/)

```
var $selects = $('select');
$('select').change(function () {
    $('option:hidden', $selects).each(function () {
        var self = this,
            toShow = true;
        $selects.not($(this).parent()).each(function () {
            if (self.value == this.value) toShow = false;
        })
        if (toShow) $(this).show();
    });
    if (this.value != 0) //to keep default option available
      $selects.not(this).children('option[value=' + this.value + ']').hide();
});
```

Comment: At the beginning of each `.change()`, you need to make all options visible.  Do the following to see why: change 1st select to value 2, second select to value 3, then change 1st select to value 1.  You will see you can no longer select value 2 in 3rd select. I actually solved a problem similar to this not too long ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15686481/iterating-over-options-from-multiple-select-boxes-in-jquery

Comment: @Roasted You linked to my jfiddle?

Comment: @Roasted This answer works, but could you explain to me why after selecting options, you can no longer select the blank option which I have set as the first option in each drop down list...this makes sure I can enter a blank team for example. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Dom Having trouble implementing your answer to my code as I'm not too experienced with JavaScript unfortunately.

Comment: @germainelol Not sure i understand your question, by blank option, you mean option value 1?

Comment: @roasted I see the problem now. The blank option is indeed option value 1, which is an option in itself, so if it is selected then of course no other drop down can be blank. Can you think of a way to fix this? This is for entering teams into a tournament, so you could imagine that you might want to have 2, 3 or more blank teams in a tournament.

Comment: Updated answer not really working now, i understand Dom comment now

Comment: @roasted Correct unfortunately, I'm having a play around with the code as well but I can't get anything done and I don't follow code very well!

Comment: @roasted No sorry. http://jsfiddle.net/m8QCZ/48/ Here is a jfiddle of what the generated code is for my page, you can see here what I am trying to achieve better. The blank option should be available to enter for ANY drop down at ALL times so that you can enter more than one team as a blank team. I can't get anything to do that just yet :/

Comment: @Dom Any chance you could apply the code to my problem? Having no luck at all